# Hide and show next carousel issue?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've bootstrap carousel and my carousel image's src is chancing on responsive that's why I'm using [this plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-For-Swapping-Image-Sources-On-Window-Resize-imageR.html) to change src of my images on responsive.

This plugin has 3 attribute `data-large`,`data-medium` and `data-small`  ---  `data-large` for desktop,`data-medium` for tablet and `data-small` for mobil devices.

> And  I have them checked with if condition and my condition works good. if my src empty then it has been hiding but this is not good sight that's why I need show next slide.
>
> > so my question is how can I show next slide ?

I try to use `$("#myCarousel").carousel('next');` but doesn't work I didn't understand why didn't work..

if you check my demo out you will understand clearly with responsive resizing window.

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/zzRwmq)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lazy_banner").imageR({
    small: "0",
    medium: "480",
    large: "1024"
  });
  lazyBanner();
});

function lazyBanner() {

  $.each($(".carousel-inner img"), function() {
    var lgData = $(this).data('large');
    var mdData = $(this).data('medium');
    var smData = $(this).data('small');
    var s = $(window).width();
    if (s > 1024) {
      if (lgData == "" || lgData == undefined) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    } else if (s > 480) {
      if (mdData == "" || mdData == undefined) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    } else if (s > 0) {
      if (smData == "" || smData == undefined) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    }
  });


}

$(window).on('resize load', function() {
  lazyBanner();
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail a>img,
.thumbnail>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img class="lazy_banner" data-large="https://image.ibb.co/dh3MSk/desktop_1.jpg" data-medium="" data-small="https://image.ibb.co/bVYc05/mobil.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="lazy_banner" data-large="" data-medium="https://images.pexels.com/photos/30865/pexels-photo-30865.jpg" data-small="https://images.pexels.com/photos/122429/leaf-nature-green-spring-122429.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="lazy_banner" data-large="https://images.pexels.com/photos/40797/wild-flowers-flowers-plant-macro-40797.jpeg" data-medium="https://www.jssor.com/demos/img/gallery/980x380/013.jpg" data-small="https://www.jssor.com/demos/img/gallery/980x380/015.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://content.anitur.com.tr/plug/imager.js"></script>
```

Comment: set min- height in *.item* or remove slide item when it empty.

Comment: but I need slide next item I need to do this

Comment: ani if you set height like min-height:175px; then next button  will align in center of slide

Comment: I understand you but my problem is not about aligment :) it's about showing next slide :) I added codepen demo

Comment: yes I remove it but when I resize again I'll need it :)

Comment: I can remove it but how can I create again my item element which I remove ? because I need to create again in else statement